# Autosizing TextView in ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, textview, android-constraintlayout

I have a chain in a `ConstraintLayout` which consists in a `TextView`, an `ImageView` and another `TextView` (doesn't need autosizing). I'd like them three to be vertically centered in the parent container (i.e. same distance to left/right).

I want the `TextView` to autosize so the text doesn't overflow. I can't use autosize with a `layout_width` set to `wrap_content` (nothing happens and the text doesn't resize). I can't set a fixed `layout_width` either since the extra space when the text isn't very long throws off the alignment.

Is there anyway to do this via XML or should I implement my own autosizing behavior?

This is a picture of what I'm trying to achieve (a center-aligned chain):
[image]

Comment: have you tried setting the width to match constraint? (0dp)?

Comment: @LeviAlbuquerque Yes, the text vanished (zero width) when I did that. Should I do something before setting the width to 0dp?

Comment: You need to set the constraints to the left and right to parent, did you do that?

Comment: @LeviAlbuquerque How can I do that? When I set those constraints, the textview stretches across the whole parent width when `layout_width` is set to `0dp`, but I need the view to share space with an `ImageView` and another `TextView` (be in line). Basically an autosizing `TextView` that's part of a `packed` chain.

Comment: I can't visualize what you're trying to achieve, can you provide a drawing of some sort?

Comment: @LeviAlbuquerque I attached a picture, hope it's clear now. I think that using a `LinearLayout` inside the `ConstraintLayout` might be a better idea?

Comment: did you manage to make this work?

Comment: @LeviAlbuquerque didn't have time to check, when I check I'll accept your answer.

Comment: Ok, let me know if  I can help you with something else :)

Comment: Any ideas? Still not working with the ConstraintLayout

Comment: @AntonShkurenko I'm positive that this question was already answered, but for some reason the answer was removed? I can't remember how this was solved, sorry. I think I ended up using a `LinearLayout` inside the `ConstraintLayout`.

Comment: Thanks :) Personally I ended using this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5535672/4142087, it works much better, than default autosize and works with wrap_content without any issues

Answer (score 3):

For TextView Auto-sizing, use `android:layout_width="0dp"`.

But make sure you apply the ViewComponents Left/Start and Right/End Constraints.

This trick is basically used instead of `android:layout_width="fill_parent"` in ConstraintLayout.

Using this, you'll achieve Auto-sizing and it will consume only the space falling under the specified constraints and no over-lapping and no spilling-out.